# Does chin augmentation (through plastic surgery) affect dental prosthesis (or vice versa)

Tags: chins, jaw, plastic-surgery, dentures

If a person wants to do both an augmentation of a jawline (through plastic surgery) and dental prosthesis (such as implants or partial dentures), is there a specific order on how these should be done?

Can chin augmentation affect the individual's bite to the point that dental prosthesis will need to be redone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question of augmentation-or-prothesis first is difficult to answer, and may even be based on the personal physiology of an individual. As such, health.se can't address that question.

Regarding the second question, "can chin-augmentation affect the individual's bite...", there's a study done with porous hydroxyapatite (not sure if chin-augmentation techniques vary) that indicates:

> **Cephalometrically, the procedure was found to provide very stable
>   results, with little change in the position of the implants and no
>   appreciable resorption of the implants and bone**.

[Chin augmentation with porous hydroxyapatite blocks.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10172030)